# Tiny insect identification in potted plants

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, pest-control

Unfortunately, the new potted soil I've bought seems to be heavily infested with insects. Firstly, I have had a fight with fungus gnats. After using parasitic nematodes about 10 days ago, I no longer see them flying around, but there are still a lot of unwanted guests that I see moving around in the pot.

Can you tell what those could be? I live in Central Europe. The pests are quite small (ca. 1 mm in length) and are running quite quickly around the pot. They don't seem to be able to jump around. Unfortunately, due to their size and quite fast movement I was not able to take a good picture, but here are two specimens, marked with red arrows. Could those be the same or different species?

[image]

Comment: They might not be insects, but more basal hexapods like springtails.

Comment: Also, they are not necessarily pests. They have a pretty high change of being **detritivores** that break down waste, not really getting in anything's way and being more helpful than harmful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are a type of [hexapod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexapoda) called [**springtails**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Springtail) (Collembola).

[image]

<sup>Common Soil springtails. Source: [UMN Extension](https://extension.umn.edu/nuisance-insects/springtails)</sup>

Springtails vary in size, shape, and color, but most are < 6 mm long (as low as ~1 mm) and many tend to be dull white/grey/yellow in color.

Many species are omnivorous soil-dwellers preferring moist and organically-rich soils.

- You will find them more frequently in over-watered plants.

For reference, I've had concurrent fungus gnat and springtail populations in my house plants before.

According to [UMN Extension](https://extension.umn.edu/nuisance-insects/springtails):

> Springtails do not have wings and cannot fly. But they can jump up to several inches using a special forked structure under the abdomen

But these insects would very unlikely survive a jump out of your plant, nor do they want to do so -- they want to be near the moist soil. I would not worry about it. (though you could water less frequently to cause their population to drop if you're concerned -- but these animals are harmless and will often help with the breakdown of the soil or removal of some soil pests depending on species and ecology).

Sources:

- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Springtail)
- [UMN Extension](https://extension.umn.edu/nuisance-insects/springtails)
- [FES Summaries](https://fesummaries.wordpress.com/2022/03/11/regional-aridity-and-local-drought-differently-shape-european-springtail-communities/)

Comment: The variety in sizes in that photo is intriguing. Do you have any idea what that depends on? Is this a species that will continue growing for as long as it has food, perhaps, so larger ones are older? Is it some sort of sexual dimorphism? Something else?